# How to get a slider's value from one view and use it in a variable in a different view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view, say View1, which has a slider. I want to be able to get the value of this slider and use it in a variable contained in a different view, say View2. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't access another view controller's views. It breaks the principle of encapsulation.

Here's what I would do:

Add a float property  to your view controller that holds the value you want to transfer.

Set it to an initial value in the view controller's init method(s). (Remember that view controllers can be loaded with both `initWithNibName:bundle:` and with `initWithCoder:`. I usually write an `-initSetup` method that I call from all the init methods that might create an object, and put my custom initialization code there.)

Attach an action to your slider. Have the action modify the value of the property.

Then in your second view controller, interrogate the first view controller's float property. Problem solved.

Comment: Wow. that was simple. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But when I do this I get an unknown receiver error.

Comment: I mean, when I reference a float and associate it to a timer variable, I get Implicit conversion of non objective c pointer to NSTimer *... What am I supposed to do? Please help.

Comment: Update your original question with "Edit: Based on the answer I got, here is the code I'm trying, but I'm getting the the following compile errors". Tell us which lines are giving you the error(s). if you're getting a runtime crash, give us the line and the stack trace of the crash.